# How to implement efficient hash cons with java HashSet

Tags: java, hashtable, hashset

I am trying to implement a [hash cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing) in java, comparable to what `String.intern` does for strings. I.e., I want a class to store all distinct values of a data type `T` in a set and provide an `T intern(T t)` method that checks whether `t` is already in the set. If so, the instance in the set is returned, otherwise `t` is added to the set and returned. The reason is that the resulting values can be compared using reference equality since two equal values returned from `intern` will for sure also be the same instance.

Of course, the most obvious candidate data structure for a hash cons is `java.util.HashSet<T>`. However, it seems that its interface is flawed and does not allow efficient insertion, because there is no method to retrieve an element that is already in the set or insert one if it is not in there.

An algorithm using `HashSet` would look like this:

```
class HashCons<T>{
    HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<>();

    public T intern(T t){
        if(set.contains(t)) {
           return ???;  // <----- PROBLEM
        } else {
           set.add(t); // <--- Inefficient, second hash lookup
           return t;
    }
}
```

As you see, the problem is twofold:

1. This solution would be inefficient since I would access the hash table twice, once for `contains` and once for `add`. But okay, this may not be a too big performance hit since the correct bucket will be in the cache after the `contains`, so `add` will not trigger a cache miss and thus be quite fast.
2. I cannot retrieve an element already in the set (see line flagged `PROBLEM`). There is just no method to retrieve the element in the set. So it is just not possible to implement this.

Am I missing something here? Or is it really impossible to build a usual hash cons with `java.util.HashSet`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible using `HashSet`. You could use some kind of `Map` instead and use your value as key *and* as value. The `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap` also happens to posess the quite convenient method

```
putIfAbsent(K key, V value)
```

that returns the value if it is already existent. However, I don't know about the performance of this method (compared to checking "manually" on non-concurrent implementations of `Map`).

Here is how you would do it using a `HashMap`:

```
class HashCons<T>{
    Map<T,T> map = new HashMap<T,T>();

    public T intern(T t){
        if (!map.containsKey(t))
            map.put(t,t);
        return map.get(t);
    }
}
```

I think the reason why it is not possible with `HashSet` is quite simple: To the set, if `contains(t)` is fulfilled, it means that the given `t` also *equals* one of the t' in the set. There is no reason for being able return it (as you already have it).

Comment: Yes, I thought already about this, too. But this is a bit hacky, as the thing *is not* a map, it is a set. Of course, I could abuse a map that has no meaningful value type (as HashSet implementation does itself internally), but it would be a shame that a usual set implementation is lacking such a feature... In addition, I would still have to access the `HashMap` two times which is a shame :(

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877776/java-weka-need-to-create-unique-instances- you need a Map to substitute any candidate with its first created identical instance. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744201/implementing-an-equivalent-to-string-intern-for-other-objects

Comment: Just a little remark here: HashSet actually uses a HashMap to store the items, so if you change it to HashMap it won't have any negative effect. Eventually, you can do the same as a HashSet does: use only the keys of a map.

Comment: A map is such a waste, each `T` is stored twice, once as key and once as value. If I store millions of values, that is a considerable waste of space. It is hilarious that there is no space efficient set in `java.util`...

Comment: @cy3er: Yes, true. I will write my own hash table then, since the thing is to big and I cannot tolerate so much space wastage.

Comment: The key and value are identical however. Yes it is a factor greater than 2 in space. And yes it is a blind spot, which I personally would immediate correct to be algebraically complete.

Comment: Well, the number of references to the instances of `T` will double, not the numbers of `T` itself. So assuming each of all n `T`s is used at least once in the rest of the program, the overhead in storing the references to the `T`s would probably rise from 2*32*n bits to 3*32*n bits.

Comment: The reason `HashSet<T>` doesn't allow items to be read out isn't that it isn't useful, but rather that the creators of `HashSet<T>` failed to recognize the usefulness [e.g. immutable-object interning]. Unfortunately, while `HashMap<T,T>` is a good substitute for `HashSet<T>`, `WeakHashMap<T,T>` doesn't work as a substitute for `WeakHashSet<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Well `HashSet` is implemented as `HashMap` wrapper in OpenJDK, so you won't win in memory usage comparing to solution suggested by aRestless.

10-min sketch

```
class HashCons<T> {
    T[] table;
    int size;
    int sizeLimit;
    HashCons(int expectedSize) {
        init(Math.max(Integer.highestOneBit(expectedSize * 2) * 2, 16));
    }

    private void init(int capacity) {
        table = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
        size = 0;
        sizeLimit = (int) (capacity * 2L / 3);
    }

    T cons(@Nonnull T key) {
        int mask = table.length - 1;
        int i = key.hashCode() & mask;
        do {
            if (table[i] == null) break;
            if (key.equals(table[i])) return table[i];
            i = (i + 1) & mask;
        } while (true);
        table[i] = key;
        if (++size > sizeLimit) rehash();
        return key;
    }

    private void rehash() {
        T[] table = this.table;
        if (table.length == (1 << 30))
            throw new IllegalStateException("HashCons is full");
        init(table.length << 1);
        for (T key : table) {
            if (key != null) cons(key);
        }
    }
}
```